# Date Filter is not working in AngularJS..?

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.schemeInfo.schemeStartDate = $filter("date")($scope.startDate,"dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Its giving me not formatted  output as

> Mon Oct 10 00:00:00 PDT 2016

Comment: I think that adding more code would be useful, especially the controller and the view.

Comment: Did you log your `$scope.startDate` ?

Comment: Could you show us the `$scope.startDate` ?

Comment: $scope.startDate = new Date($scope.schemeInfo.schemeStartDate);

Comment: @RajatLutade Why have you unaccepted the answer ?

Comment: @suzo I am still facing same problem..? need concrete solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your "$scope.startDate" is a date object.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter)
{
    $scope.myDate = new Date('Mon Oct 10 00:00:00 PDT 2016');
    $scope.myDateFiltered = $filter('date')($scope.myDate, 'dd/MM/yy');
}]);
```

Hope this helps.

*FYI:* Created the jsfiddle, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/suzo/M4sWc/3/)